# Why didn't French people take the decimal positional system?

Tags: france

I heard that mathematics in France is very hard because it didn't follow the decimal positional system (promoted by Leonardo Fibonacci in Europe), and I searched and found from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) that:

> After the French Revolution (1789–1799), the new French government promoted the extension of the decimal system. Some of those pro-decimal efforts—such as decimal time and the decimal calendar—were unsuccessful.

I learned that the system includes vigesimal and sexagesimal, and France ranked 2nd in [countries by number of Fields Medalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_number_of_Fields_Medalists). I wonder why only France cannot completely adopt the decimal positional system and how and why does its own system benefit its mathematics?

Comment: IMO, you are mixing number system with [Metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_measurement#Metric_system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you heard is not true. The French do indeed use the decimal position system, which you can verify in any French textbook on mathematics. Consequently, mathematics is no easier or harder in France than it is anywhere else.

You may be confused by the names of numbers in French. For example, 70 is "soixante-dix" (literally translated as "sixty-ten"), 71 is "soixante-onze" ("sixty-eleven"), 80 is "quatre-vingt" ("four-twenty"), 90 is "quatre-vingt-dix" ("four-twenty-ten"), and so on. (As a small aside, I've also heard 90 called "nonante" by Swiss French speakers, so there are dialect variations in the names as well.)

But these are just the names of numbers, and have nothing to do with using the decimal  position system or not. The names might have been originally derived from vigesimal or sexagesimal, but French speakers do not think about the etymology when doing mathematics any more or less than they or anyone else thinks about the etymology of any word while using it.

The quote from Wikipedia that you cite in your question has more to do with the metric system, which is yet another thing entirely. The metric system is certainly inspired by the decimal position system, but it is a system of measurements and not a system of numerals for representing numbers. For example, the Americans use the decimal  position system, but have not adopted the metric system.